# There is not enough values to unpack, how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I keep getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1). Is this an issue of balancing both sides of the equal sign, and if so, how do I balance it?

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

Comment: ...are you passing three command line arguments?

Comment: jonsharpe, I have, and they turned out to be invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need call the script with exactly three arguments:

```
$ python myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Inside the script, you could explicitly check it, e.g.:

```
if len(argv) != 4:
    print("Please use exactly three arguments")
    exit(1)

script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse 4 args from the script call. If your script is called `python_test.py` then try:

```
python python_test.py 4 5 6
```

and you will get

```
('The script is called:', 'python_args_test.py')
('Your first variable is:', '4')
('Your second variable is:', '5')
('Your third variable is:', '6')
```

Notice that the first argument to the python call is the name of the script. If you just try to run the script without additional arguments you will get the error you show because only the name of the script is given as an argument.